# selecting unique rows from one table according to another table and then sorting it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
communications:
--------------------------------------------------
id  |   subject     |   timestamp   |   starter
--------------------------------------------------

messagepartners
-------------------------------------------------
id  |   commid      |   userid  |   type
-------------------------------------------------
```

the messagepartners table stores the ids of users who are participating in a conversation (stored in communications table). 
the column commid in messagepartners stores the corresponding communications id (column id in communications)

for a specific user with the id of userid, I want to get a list of communications in which userid is participating. the list should contain no duplicates and be sorted by timestamp.

how should I write a sql query for this?
Thanks

Comment: you have to use a join.  have you tried anything at all?  this is simple sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it in steps

Here is a way to join the tables

```
SELECT *
FROM communications as c
JOIN messagepartners as p on c.id = p.commid
```

Filter by userid

```
SELECT *
FROM communications as c
JOIN messagepartners as p on c.id = p.commid
WHERE p.userid = X
```

Data we want

```
SELECT c.id, c.subject, c.timestamp
FROM communications as c
JOIN messagepartners as p on c.id = p.commid
WHERE p.userid = X
```

no dups

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.subject, c.timestamp
FROM communications as c
JOIN messagepartners as p on c.id = p.commid
WHERE p.userid = X
```

I suggest running each of these steps and understanding why you get the results you do at each step.

Answer (score 0):

The following query do what you want:

```
SELECT 
    b.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            commid
        FROM
            messagepartners
        WHERE 
            userid = 1234
        GROUP BY
            commid
    ) a
    INNER JOIN communications b ON (a.commid = b.id)
ORDER BY
    B.timestamp
;
```

Don't forget to replace 1234 with the user id.